# Consistently subset matrix to a vector and avoid colnames?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, subset

I would like to know if there is R syntax to extract a column from a matrix and *always* have no name attribute on the returned vector (I wish to rely on this behaviour).

My problem is the following inconsistency:

- when a matrix has more than one row and I do `myMatrix[, 1]` I will get the first column of `myMatrix` with no name attribute. This is what I want.
- when a matrix has **exactly one row** and I do `myMatrix[, 1]`, I will get the first column of `myMatrix` **but it has the first colname as its name**.

I would like to be able to do `myMatrix[, 1]` and *consistently* get something with **no name**.

An example to demonstrate this:

```
# make a matrix with more than one row,
x <- matrix(1:2, nrow=2)
colnames(x) <- 'foo'
#      foo
# [1,]   1
# [2,]   2

# extract first column. Note no 'foo' name is attached.
x[, 1]
# [1] 1 2

# now suppose x has just one row (and is a matrix)
x <- x[1, , drop=F]
# extract first column
x[, 1]
# foo    # <-- we keep the name!!
#   1
```

Now, the documentation for `[` (`?'['`) mentions this behaviour, so it's not a bug or anything (although, why?! why this inconsistency?!):

> A vector obtained by matrix indexing will be unnamed **unless ‘x’ is one-dimensional** when the row names (if any) will be indexed to provide names for the result.

**My question is**, is there a way to do `x[, 1]` such that the result is  *always* unnamed, where `x` is a matrix?

Is my only hope `unname(x[, 1])` or is there something analogous to `[`'s `drop` argument? Or is there an option I can set to say "always unname"? Some trick I can use (somehow override `[`'s behaviour when the extracted result is a vector?)

Comment: since you want to have a one column matrix , I would do `as.vector(x[,1])`..

Comment: `"dimnames<-"(x,NULL)[,1]`

Comment: @agstudy: I don't want a on-column matrix, I just want the result to be unnamed regardless of what it is. In any case, `as.vector(x[,1])` produces a *vector*, which is *not* a one-column matrix, and still has the names attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update on why the code below works** (as far as I can tell)

Subsetting with `[` is handled using functions contained in the R source file [`subset.c`](http://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/subset.c) in `~/src/main`. When using matrix indexing to subset a matrix, the function `VectorSubset` is called. When there is more than one index used (i.e., one each for rows and columns as in `x[,1]`), then `MatrixSubset` is called.

The function `VectorSubset` only assigns names to 1-dimensional arrays being subsetted. Since a matrix is a 2-D array, no names are assigned to the result when using matrix indexing. The function `MatrixSubset`, however, does attempt to pass on dimnames under certain circumstances.

---

**Therefore,** the matrix indexing you refer to in the quote from the help page seems to be the key:

```
x <- matrix(1)
colnames(x) <- "foo"
x[, 1]  ## 'Normal' indexing
# foo 
#   1 
x[matrix(c(1, 1), ncol = 2)]  ## Matrix indexing
# [1] 1
```

And with a wider 1-row matrix:

```
xx <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 1)
colnames(xx) <- sprintf('foo%i', seq_len(ncol(xx)))
xx[, 6]  ## 'Normal' indexing
# foo6 
#    6 
xx[matrix(c(1, 6), ncol = 2)]  ## Matrix indexing
# [1] 6
```

With a matrix with both dimensions > 1:

```
yy <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 2, dimnames = list(NULL,
  sprintf('foo%i', 1:5)))

yy[cbind(seq_len(nrow(yy)), 3)]  ## Matrix indexing
# [1] 5 6
```

Comment: @mathematical.coffee, after further investigation, I am fairly confident that matrix indexing will consistently return an unnamed subset of a matrix.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, matrix indexing. Unfortunately no less clunky than `unname(x[, 1])` though! Thanks for the digging you did to discover this!

Comment: @mathematical.coffee, yeah, you're probably good to go with `unname` as you suggested! I find the periodic perusal of the R source code interesting and humbling, so thanks for the excuse.